# Why is .toCharArray() giving garbage value?

Tags: java, string, data-structures, stack

Below mentioned code is for reversing k elements in a string of n size. Line 3 is returning garbage value. Can anyone please help me out on this.

```
class Solution{
     public String reverseStr(String s, int k){
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack();
         int i;
        for(i = 0; i < k; i++){
            st.push(ch[i]);
        }
         i = 0;
         while(!st.isEmpty()){
             ch[i] = st.pop();
         }
         return ch.toString();
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage value"?

Comment: Give an example of your input and output strings.

Comment: The [Answer by Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605994/642706) is correct and should be accepted for fixing your specific problem. However, such code using `char` is obsolete. The `char` type is unable to represent even half of the characters defined by Unicode and supported by Java. Instead, learn to use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) integers. see my version of your code adapted to code points [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0PfqWc). My code handles an input of `"dog"` whereas your code breaks.

Answer (score 3):

## Increment `i`

There is a mistake in this part of your code:

```
i = 0;
while(!st.isEmpty()){
    ch[i] = st.pop();
}
```

Note that `i` remains `0` the whole time, so you are assigning to `ch[0]` in each iteration of the loop. You probably meant to increment `i` in the loop:

```
i = 0;
while(!st.isEmpty()){
    ch[i++] = st.pop();
}
```

## Generate `String` from `char` array

Note that the last line of your code:

```
return ch.toString();
```

will [not return what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4). If you want to convert the `char` array to a `String` containing the characters, do this instead:

```
return new String(ch);
```

Comment: Even fixed, though the "garbage" is the default `toString()`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- indeed, that's another bug, added to my answer.

Comment: He must have to add null check condition just after function start **if (s != null )**